# Install libraires on Ubuntu for Python3 and not Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu

My problem is quite simple. I would like to install `PyQuery` using `pip`. So I write the following in the command line:

```
sudo pip install PyQuery
```

It said that `PyQuery` installed successfully. Then, if I write in the command line:

```
python3 test.py
```

It is said that it does not recognise the `import PyQuery`. However, if I replace `python3` with `python`, this error message does not appear.

I suppose the problem is that pip installs modules for Python2 and not Python3, but I do not know how to change that.

> Python2 version: 2.7
>   Python3 version: 3.4

Comment: try using `pip3` instead? Linux uses the first `pip` it finds, which is usually your system Python's pip (e.g. Python2). Python3's pip is symlinked to `pip3` in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Each installed version of python have its own version of pip executable (at least for ubuntu), e.g. `python2` have related `pip2`, `python3` - `pip3`.

`python` and `pip` is just defaults which is simplinks to `python2` or `python3` binary.

So you can use

```
pip3 install <package>
```

in most cases when you need to install package for python 3.

#### Lets find out how it works

*`pip` is not binary!*

Look at command for running pip python package, by executing following command:

```
$ less $(which pip)
```

Output will be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==1.5.4','console_scripts','pip'
__requires__ = 'pip==1.5.4'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
    )
```

Actually, most of commands in linux aren't binaries. A lot of them just helpful bindings, just like in case with pip.

```
$ ls -lah $(which pip)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 281 чер 17 00:52 /usr/bin/pip
```

You can find [simple description of how executable scripts works on linux](http://www.linfo.org/create_shell_1.html). It is written for bash scripts but applied for any interpreted language: python, javascript, ruby, etc.

*So, if pip is not binary, then what does this script?*

[RTFM about pip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/installing/index.html), in few words, pip is just a python module and can be executed as any other python module, look at [PEP 0338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/#import-statements-and-the-main-module), e.g.

```
$ python -m pip install <package>
```

have same same effect as for command

```
$ pip install <package>
```

#### Summary

`pip` is python script that runs pip package with passed parameters. Package relative for python version in `$ which pip` file. If you will open your pip script, you will find for which python version it is related for.

In my case it is:

```
$ head -1 $(which pip)
#!/usr/bin/python
$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.6
```

or oneliner

```
$ $(expr substr `head -1 $(which pip)` 3 100) -V
Python 2.7.6
```